# Heat release from a uncoated vs coated titanium

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction, thermoelectricity

Is heat released quicker in a titanium (uncoated) metal or titanium with silicone coating?

Comment: common sense would suggest the one without the coating in the way, especially as metal is great at conducting heat and silicone (a kind of plastic/rubber material) is not.